# Change AeroFS folder location

Tags: windows, linux, aerofs

I'm using AeroFS on a Linux/Windows dual-boot computer, and I need to find a way to change the location of the AeroFS folder so that it can be accessible from Windows as well as Ubuntu. Is there any way to share an AeroFS folder between two operating systems on a dual-boot computer?

Comment: I simply removed the AeroFS folder, and then I was prompted to select a new location for the folder.

Comment: I hope that this will make it possible to share an AeroFS folder between two partitions on a dual-boot system - I'm still testing it to see if it works.

Comment: It appears that there is already a discussion of this issue: http://support.aerofs.com/forums/147816-linux-problems/suggestions/3249652-support-for-a-dual-boot-system It appears that a single AeroFS folder isn't properly recognized between Linux and Windows.